# Google Chrome extension crashes on update.

Tags: crash, google-chrome-extension

we are developing an extension, hosted in the Google chrome web store.recently - we've got complaints from our users that sometime they get a notification window saying "the extension crashed, click here to reload".

after a short research we found out that this is happening only when we upload a new version to the Chrome Web Store.
we started to look it up online and found no documentation what so ever for this, so we started to check for it ourselves.

we tried to see what exactly can cause this problem and if we can identify a distinctive cause.
our tries included updating only the manifest.json file, a css file, a js file or not changing nothing at all but the version number, and on each change we've uploaded a new version and update it in about 10 different machines.
the results were the same, when on each update we made, it caused the extension to crash on just a few of the machines, while updating perfectly fine on the others. each time different machines acted differently.

then, we thought it might be related to the fact we have a timer working in the background page, and it might be happening just at the time it is working.
so we tried to raise the timer's frequency (from 5 seconds to 100 millisecond), and it still acted the same, crashing on only 3 out of the 10 machines.

we ran out of ideas now, and it really causing a problem in terms of user experience to our extension's users.

did someone had this problem, or came across any extension crashes on version update?
is it a known bug in chrome's extension engine or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: Haven't heard of this issue. Please create a reduced test case (simple extension), log a bug on new.crbug.com and attach the test to the bug.

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior, but not for an update, but rather when doing an inline install.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and I think I found the cause.  Do you by chance, override the new tab page?

I am able to reproduce the problem 100% of the time and when I remove the new tab override from the manifest, the problem goes away.
I opened an issue: [Issue 104401](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104401)